# Java: is there a way for function to allow all child class as return type using generics?

Tags: java, generics

Coming across a problem that I could not make a function to allow a generic return type for all the child class of a parent class.

Is there a way to create a function that allows me to return any of these children class type base on an argument?

I have the following parent class:

```
abstract class Number {
    int res = 1;
    abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
        int res = 100;

        public T setNum(int num) {
            this.res = num;
            return self();
        }
        abstract Number build();

        abstract T self();
    }

    Number(Builder<?> builder) {
        res = builder.res;
    }
}
```

and some children class:

```
class One extends Number{
    private int size = 1;
    static class Builder extends Number.Builder<Builder> {
        private int size = -1;
        public Builder setSize(int size) {
            this.size = size;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public One build() {
            return new One(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    private One(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        size = builder.size;
    }
}

class Two extends Number {
    private String size = String.valueOf(1);
    static class Builder extends Number.Builder<Builder> {
        private String size;
        public Builder setSize(String size) {
            this.size = size;
            return self();
        }

        @Override
        public Two build() {
            return new Two(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }

    private Two(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        size = builder.size;
    }
}
```

Note the parent class and child classes are not done yet, but it is going to have a similar format with just more fields so this would still apply

This is something that I want to achieve:

```
public <T> T loadNumber(String id) {
    if (id.equals('1')) {
        return new ONE.Builder.build(); // this will report error right now
    }
    elif (id.equals('2')) {
        return new TWO.Builder.build(); // this will report error right now
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that type arguments are specified by the caller. Your method

```
public <T> T loadNumber(String id) {
```

can be called like

```
Two two = loadNumber("One");
```

causing the compiler to infer

```
Two two = loadNumber<Two>("One");
```

which is why the compiler expects your method implementation to conjure a `T` out of thin air, and is not satisfied with a `One`. After all, `T` could stand for `Two`, as in the example above, and `One` isn't `Two`.

Put differently, the method signature

```
public <T> T loadNumber(String id) {
```

doesn't make sense, because the method must return a `T`, but has no way to determine, at runtime, what `T` is (due to type erasure, methods can't reflect on their type parameters).

So you have two choices:

Either you return the base type

```
public Number loadNumber(String id) {
```

and have the caller, who presumably knows which type the `id` he passed corresponds to, cast it to that type,

or you use an ID that whose type is itself generic and describes the type it maps to:

```
interface Builder<P extends Number, B extends Builder<P>> {
    P build();
    B self();
}

interface ID<P extends Number> {
    Builder<P, ?> builder();

    static ID<One> one = One.Builder::new;
    static ID<Two> two = Two.Builder::new;
}
```

and then you can declare

```
public <N extends Number> N loadNumber(ID<N> id) {
    return id.builder().build();
}
```

and use it like

```
One one = loadNumber(ID.one);
Two two = loadNumber(ID.two);
```

but not

```
One one = loadNumber(ID.two); // compilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return any child class by simply using the **parent class as a return type**, in your case:

```
public Number loadNumber(String id) {
// your code implementation
}
```

---

Now, **to save this into a variable** you can use the same logic and declare the variable as the parent type. After the method returns, the *variable will be casted into the whatever child class instance it returned*, for example in your case:

```
Number obj = loadNumber("1");
```

The `obj` object *will cast to an instance of* `One` *class*. You can **test this** by printing out the object class after the above line:

```
System.out.println(obj.getClass());
```

This should print out `class One` or the name of whatever child class you saved into the variable.

Comment: Yea but I want it to return the child class type instead so I don't have to cast it outside. Is there a more generic way to do it without casting at all? (Please do let me know if this is a bad practise in general)

Comment: If you use the same logic to save it into a variable say `Number obj = loadNumber("1");` the object should be casted to whatever child class instance is returned from the method.

You can test this by printing out the object class after the above line `System.out.println(obj.getClass());`. This should print out the child class name. I will update the answer to reflect this information.